# Class not registered : SSIS Package 2005

Tags: .net, sql-server, ssis

I have a SSIS Package in 2005. When I run the package through the "SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio" then it runs very well, but when I run the package through the .bat file it shows the below issue :

> Source: SSIS_Extract Connection manager "MYDataba
>   se"
>      Description: An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040154.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"  H
>   result: 0x80040154  Description: "Class not registered".
>   End Error

Below is the .bat file content

```
Echo on

DTEXEC /FILE "SSIS_Extract.dtsx"
/CONFIGFILE "Extract_Config.dtsConfig"  /MAXCONCURRENT
" -1 " /CHECKPOINTING OFF  /REPORTING EW 

echo %ErrorLevel% 

pause
```

The same SSIS Package is running in Windows 7 64 bit, but not in the Windows 7 32. There might be issue in the 64 to 32 bit. Is there any any way to convert the existing ssis package so that it can be run in the Windows 7 32 bit or Windows Sever 2012 32 bit.

Anyone can help me out to solve this issue.

Comment: Post the contents of "the bat file". How are you running it? Double clicking it or running it through SQL Server agent?

Comment: Added the .bat file content. Running the bat file with double click or Right click with administrator.

Comment: So is there anything interesting about the connection manager mentioned? It might be a 32/64 bit thing. VS runs as 32 bit. The DTExec.exe you reference might be 64 or 32 bit. Take a look at this - try explicitly using the 32 bit DTExec. http://help.pragmaticworks.com/dtsxchange/scr/FAQ%20-%20How%20to%20run%20SSIS%20Packages%20using%2032bit%20drivers%20on%2064bit%20machine.htm

Comment: Specifically, try putting `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn` in front of your `DTExec` for force the 32 bit version (folder might be slightly different but you get the idea - its gotta be in (x86) folder)

Comment: I dont have (x86) folder.

Comment: Can you do the following: 1. Use this link http://help.pragmaticworks.com/dtsxchange/scr/Running%20Packages%20on%2064%20Bit%20Machine.htm to check whether BIDS is debugging in 32 or 64 bit mode. 2. At a command prompt type `DTEXEC /?` and see whether it is the 32bit or 64bit version. 3. Search on your computer for DTExec.EXE. How many are there?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your support. I got the solution. The OLEDB connection was mentioned in the SSIS Package

> Data Source=xxxxx;User ID=xxxx; password=xxxx;Initial
>   Catalog=xxxxxxxxxxxx;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1

I changed the provide in the connection string and it works fine now.

> Data Source=xxxxx;User ID=xxxx; password=xxxx;Initial
>   Catalog=xxxxxxxxxxxx;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1

Comment: It doesn't explain why it worked one way and not the other but I'm glad you solved your problem and its good of you to come back and post it